# hibernate interceptor oncollectionupdate when updating more than one collection

Tags: hibernate, interceptor

Here is an exemple of class
`class Foo{
   List<Bar> firstList = new ArrayList();
   List<Bar> secondList = new ArrayList();
}`
When update both lists, onCollectionUpdate interceptor is called twice. My problem is how to know, in onCollectionUpdate(Object collection, Serializable key) method,  which collection matches to which Foo parameter.

**EDIT**: Foo class has also an Integer parameter, which is its id.
`private Integer id`

Comment: What is the Foo parameter? Could you debug& What is the **key** parameter's value?

Comment: @StanislavL when debugging key parameter's value is Foo object id